# Why is my join not filtering out dates? SQL syntax

Tags: sql, join, filtering, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to join two tables: attributes and inventory. I need to obtain the total inventory for our categories in different warehouses.

I have two tables:

1. `Inventory`: this table can tell me the inventory of an item on a certain date.
2. `Attributes`: this table can tell me the current classification of an item.

Usually I run a query  like this to obtain the inventory per classification, I use inventory table but I make a nested query on WHERE clause to get the inventory from the ItemId that falls in an unique classification:

```
select
    warehouse_id,
    ItemId,
    sum(on_hand_quantity) as inventory
from 
    inventory a
where 
    and warehouse_id in ('Warehouse1', 'Warehouse2')
    and to_char(snapshot_day,'YYYY,MM,DD') = 'YYYY,MM,DD' 
    and ItemId in (Select ItemId
from 
    attributes
where 
    Class  in ('Class1'))
group by   
    1,2
```

Since I ran this query once for every classification I tried to make a join that looks like this to get the on_hand_quantity using the Class instead of the item Id, the query runs but returns an inventory quantity way higher than the real one. I think that sum() functions are taking all historical values, instead of filtering by the date stated on where clause but I haven't found a way around this.

```
SELECT 
    uic.snapshot_day,
    uic.warehouse_id,
    Sum(Case When att.Class = 'Class1' 
         Then uic.on_hand_quantity Else 0 End) as Class1_inventory
    Sum(Case When att.Class= 'Class2' 
         Then uic.on_hand_quantity Else 0 End) as Class2_inventory,
    Sum(Case When att.stamp = 'Class3' 
         Then uic.on_hand_quantity Else 0 End) as Class3_inventory

FROM inventory uic  JOIN attributes att 
    ON uic.ItemId = att.ItemId

WHERE 
    AND uic.warehouse_id in (‘Warehouse1’, ‘Warehouse2’)
    AND att.class in ('Class1','Class2','Class3')
    AND to_char(uic snapshot_day,'YYYY,MM,DD') = 'YYYY,MM,DD' 
    
GROUP BY 2,1
```

Comment: ItemID is not unique to the Inventory table nor it is unique to the attributes table.

Always be wary of join clauses that don't reference a primary key on either table

Comment: `sql` is a poor tag to use: *Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.)* see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql

Answer (score 0):

If this is literally what you using: `to_char(uic.snapshot_day,'YYYY,MM,DD') = 'YYYY,MM,DD'` it simply won't work. When you convert a date to a string you get results like "`2023,04,03`"  which will never equal "`YYYY,MM,DD`"

You also want to avoid changing every row's date value to a string, instead use a date in the comparison. e.g.

```
uic.snapshot_day = to_date('2023-04-03','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or, if the column is a timestamp or similar:

```
uic.snapshot_day >= to_date('2023-04-03','YYYY-MM-DD')
and uic.snapshot_day < to_date('2023-04-04','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

nb: "to_date" is an assumption as the dbms isn't identified, the syntax for your dbms may be different.